# Linear functional and a bounded norm

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm trying to work through some example questions for my class but there is no mention of "Piecewise affine functions" anywhere and I'm completely stumped on how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated please.

[image]

Comment: A "piecewise affine" function is a continuous function that is of the form $m_i\cdot x + s_i$ on each of the finitely many subintervals $[a_i,a_{i+1}]$ that the domain $[-1,1]$ is decomposed into. Maybe you know them as "piecewise linear".

Answer (score 0):

a) Note that
$$
||\phi(f)|| = \left|\int_{-1}^{0}f(x)dx - \int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx\right| \le \left|\int_{-1}^{0}f(x)dx\right| + \left|\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx\right| \le \left|\int_{-1}^{0}\left(\sup_{x\in(-1,1)}f(x) \right)dx\right| + \left|\int_{0}^{1}\left(\sup_{x\in(-1,1)}f(x) \right)dx\right| = 2||f||.
$$
So $||\phi||\le 2$.

b) Let 
$$
g_n(x) = 
\begin{cases}
   \max\{-nx,-1\} & \text{if } 0\le x \le 1 \\
   \min\{-nx,1\}       & \text{if } -1 \le x \le 0
  \end{cases}.
$$
Then $||g_n|| = 1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and
$$
||\phi(g_n(x))|| = \left|\int_{-1}^{0}g_n(x)dx - \int_{0}^{1}g_n(x)dx\right| = \frac{2n-1}{2n} + \frac{2n-1}{2n} = \frac{2n-1}{n}\stackrel{n\rightarrow\infty}{\rightarrow} 2.
$$
So $||\phi||$ must be two, as for any number $0 < a <2$ we can find an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a < ||\phi(g_n)|| < 2$.

For part ii). Notice that
$$
||\psi(x)|| = \left|\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ix_i\right| \le \left|\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i \max_{1\le j\le n}x_j\right| \le \sum_{i=1}^{n}|a_i| \max_{1\le j\le n}|x_j| = \sum_{i=1}^{n}|a_i| ||x||_\infty = ||a||_1||x||_\infty,
$$
so $||\psi||\le||a||_1$. Now take $x = (1,\ldots,1)$, then $||\psi(x)|| = ||a||_1$, so  $||\psi|| = ||a||_1$.

Comment: Thankyou for this, it makes sense. Could you possibly help me on part ii) ?

Comment: Part 2 is actually a bit easier than what I've already shown you. So first have a go at it yourself. Let me know if you get stuck at a certain phase;)

Comment: Okay so I've been researching different norms so I understand that but with regards to the L^p spaces when I look those up it is taking me back to how it relates to a norm. Is there a proper definition of L^p spaces that I need to know or am I following the completely wrong track here?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space for example for the standard norms on the $l^p$ spaces.

Comment: Okay I've looked and looked and researched about this and I honestly don't know how to proceed. The hint is actually making it harder because I don't see why that helps at all. Is there any other advice you could possibly give me on this please.

Comment: I added the solution to part two to my answer. Try and explain what exactly you don't understand.